# Fischer distribution equalities

Tags: statistics

Suppose the random variable $W$ has an $F$-distribution $F(r_1,r_2)$. My probability and statistics textbook writes:
if $\alpha = P[W \geq F_{\alpha}(r_1,r_2)]$,

then 
$\alpha = P[W  \leq F_{1-\alpha}(r_1,r_2)] = P[\frac {1}{W} \geq \frac {1} {F_{1-\alpha}(r_1,r_2)}]$ (not sure why this last equality is true)

and moreover that 
$P[\frac {1} {w} \leq F_{\alpha}(r_2,r_1)] = \alpha$. (why does reversing the order of $(r_1,r_2)$ have this effect?)

Any insights into how these equalities are derived much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that one of the definitions of $F(n_1, n_2)$ distribution is by independent two scaled $\chi^2$ random variable. Namely, if $ U_1 \sim \chi^2(n_1)$ and $U_2 \sim \chi^2(n_2)$, thus
$$
F(n_1, n_2) =
 \frac{U_1/n_1}{ U_2/n_2},
$$
and 
$$
F(n_2, n_1) =
 \frac{U_2/n_2}{ U_1/n_1} =\frac{1}{F(n_1, n_2)}\, .
$$

Comment: For $g(x) = 1/x $ for $x > 0$ if $\mathbb{P}( X \le x) = \alpha$ then  $\mathbb{P}( g(X) \ge g(x) ) = \alpha$. For some more details you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371494/show-prove-that-f-alpha-n-m-1-f-1-alpha-m-n/2372564#2372564)